# ob_start("ob_gzhandler") is giving error

Tags: php, gzip

I am using ob_start("ob_gzhandler") to gzip the response that I am sending from my API. It is working fine on my developer machine as well as on staging environment.

However, when I deployed my API in a production environment it is giving me an error that server is not responding.

I think there is some extension to be enabled for using gzip compression. Can you please help me in the resolution of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php):

> Note:
>
> ob_gzhandler() requires the zlib extension.

Install the [zlib](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zlib.php) extension. You can check if the extension is installed by executing the following code:

```
if (extension_loaded('zlib')){
    echo "zlib installed";
} else {
    echo "zlib is not installed";
}
```

Comment: This extension is installed on the server. I have checked through phpinfo() and found that zlib extension is enabled. Can you please suggest some other measures that I can perform to resolve the issue.